# Do I need to equip the weapon to make it available for the next missions?

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

While playing the mission [Operation: Grifter](https://guides.gamepressure.com/thebureauxcomdeclassified/guide.asp?ID=21251), I found the laser pistol on the floor.

Will it be available on the next missions if I don't finish this mission with the pistol?

Comment: Iirc you need to equip it once then throw if you want, then you can equip it next mission. Although laser pistol can only be equiped by your or support classes.

Comment: Iirc you need to equip it once then throw if you want, then you can equip it next mission. Although laser pistol can only be equiped by your or support classes.

Comment: @ken That seems to be right. Why don´t you put that in an answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iirc you need to equip it once then throw if you want, then you can equip it next mission. Although laser pistol can only be equiped by you or support classes